# Announcing Moderators Pro Tempore!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: anonymous2]
[image: Aurora0001]
[image: Helmar]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to take moment to say: Thank you.  I feel unbelievably honoured by the trust laid on me.  I also feel a huge amount of hope as we look forward to the season which is ahead of us: I firmly believe that Internet of Things Stack Exchange has a glorious future ahead of it.

As we move away from our private beta into the bright full moon of our new public beta existence, let us continue to strive always forward.  May we keep promoting, asking, answering, voting, and working to make this site not a mediocre flub or even a good site, but an excellent place to exchange questions and answers.

P.S.: I solemnly vow to do my utmost to keep *[His Madnificents](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/12/aurora0001)* in check.*

<sub>* If you didn't understand that joke, you need to spend more time in [Chat of Things](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49682/chat-of-things).</sub>

Comment: So say we all !